# Convert Ninject to Unity

Tags: c#, ninject, unity-container

I'm currently migrating some working Ninject code over to Microsoft Unity and am a bit stuck on this particular conversion.

```
Bind<MyDbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope().WithConstructorArgument("connectionString", configurationService.MySqlConnectionString);
Bind<IUnitOfWork>().ToMethod(ctx => ctx.Kernel.Get<MyDbContext>());
Bind<DbContext>().ToMethod(ctx => ctx.Kernel.Get<MyDbContext>());
```

Any help would be appreciated, in providing the Unity 3.0 version of this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using the [`Unity.MVC4`](http://nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc4/) NuGet (which would register a custom DependencyResolver for you):

```
container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, MyDbContext>(
    new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(),
    new InjectionFactory(
        c => new MyDbContext(configurationService.MySqlConnectionString)
    )
);
container.RegisterType<DbContext, MyDbContext>(
    new HierarchicalLifetimeManager()
);
```

Comment: Thanks Darin, you're a genius! OH an yes I am using the noted NuGet package.